# Angular Unit Testing For Subscribe methods

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

`I want to unit test my subscribe functions. Please help me out.
ts

```
export class EmployeeFormDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  employeeData : any;
  id !: number;`your text`
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployeeDetails();
  }
getEmployeeDetails(){
  this.api.getEmployee()
  .subscribe(res =>{
   this.employeeData= res;
   console.log(res);
  })
}
deleteEmployee(row : any){
  this.api.deleteEmployee(row.id)
  .subscribe(res=>{
    this.getEmployeeDetails();
  )
}
postEmployeeDetails() {
    this.employeeModelObj.firstName = this.registrationForm.value.firstName;
    this.employeeModelObj.lastName = this.registrationForm.value.lastName;
    this.employeeModelObj.startDate = this.registrationForm.value.startDate;
    this.employeeModelObj.endDate = this.registrationForm.value.endDate;
    this.employeeModelObj.experience = this.registrationForm.value.experience;
    this.api.postEmployee(this.employeeModelObj)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.router.navigate(['employeeFormDetails'])
      })
  }
  getEmployeeDetails(Experience: string) {
     this.filteredList = this.api.getemployeeByExperience(Experience)
    console.log(this.filteredList); 
  }
```

}
````your text`

I have written a unit test case for my get method and it has worked.. But I want to unit test for my delete method, get by experience method and my post method.
spec.ts

```
 it('should call get method', ()=>{
  const response: EmployeeModel[] =[];
  spyOn(service, 'getEmployee').and.returnValue(of(response))
  component.getEmployeeDetails();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.employeeData).toEqual(response);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using fakeAsync? Should look somewhat like this:

```
 it('should call get method', fakeAsync(()=>{
      const response: EmployeeModel[] =[];
      spyOn(service, 'getEmployee').and.returnValue(of(response))
      component.getEmployeeDetails();
      tick();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.employeeData).toEqual(response);
  }));
```

To be fair, this component seems rather complex. Using subscribe inside components becomes rather tricky anyways, I believe you should consider using a pattern like this: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-component-design-how-to-avoid-custom-event-bubbling-and-extraneous-properties-in-the-local-component-tree/

Comment: How should I write a delete method for testing?

Comment: I tried to write it down but then I failed to understand why you would call "get" after "delete"? If the answer I already gave was correct, an upvote would be appreicated. Writing a test for the delete method should just be a copy paste ;)